# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x,\, 0 < \Re s < 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Evaluate
> $$\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$$
> for $0 < \Re(s) < 2$.

This is an exercise from an elementary complex analysis textbook.
**My attempt:**
If $0 < \Re(s) < 1$, we can evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-s}e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-s}e^{-ix}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
using residues (the integration paths are sectors in the 1st and 4st quadrants, respectively), yielding
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x = \Gamma(1-s)\cos\frac{\pi}{2}s$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\cos x\,\mathrm{d}x = \Gamma(1-s)\sin\frac{\pi}{2}s.$$
If $1 < \Re(s) < 2$, we can integrate by part,
\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
= & \frac{1}{1-s}\left.x^{1-s}\sin x\right|_0^\infty
- \frac{1}{1-s}\int_0^\infty x^{1-s}\cos x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
= & \Gamma(1-s)\cos\frac{\pi}{2}s
\end{align}
using results obtained above.
However, when $\Re(s) = 1$, integration by part breaks down, as $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1-s}\sin x$ diverges in this case.
If uniform convergence for $\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$ when $0 < \Re(s) < 2$ can be proved, then even integration by part is unnecessary, as we can extend the result from $0 < \Re(s) < 1$ using analytic continuation. But I can at most do it with real $s$; I can't work around the complex case.
Could someone show me how to get past the line $\Re(s) = 1$?

Comment: What is the difference between showing convergence (uniform on compacts) between the real and complex case? In both cases you have something decreasing at infinity times something bounded well so you can apply the second mean value theorem or Abel Dirichlet method at infinity, while at zero you are good by using $\sin x \sim x$ there and absolute convergence; $x^{-\sigma-it}\sin x= x^{-\sigma}(\sin x \cos t\log x+...$

Comment: As in your splendid answer, to use Dirichlet we have to deal with $\int \sin(x\pm t\log x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. When $t = 0$ it's trivial, but when $t \ne 0$ it's simply beyond my capability. I guess it's just that I didn't learn calculus so well...

Comment: The second mean value theorem for integrals is always useful when you deal with integrals of monotonic times oscillating as well as integrals of $\sin F(x)$ and the like with $F'$ monotonic and nonvanishing anywhere as you can write $(F'\sin F)/F'$ then; if $F'$ is monotonic but has zeroes splitting the integration domain carefully may work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, let's show that $$f(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$$ is (defined and) analytic on $\Omega$ given by $0 < \Re s <2$, so by analytic continuation the result obtained for $0 < \Re s <1$ extends to $\Omega$

Fix a compact set $K \subset \Omega$ so $0<a \le \sigma \le b <2$ and $|t| \le C$ for $s=\sigma+it \in K$ and let's show that the integrals converge uniformly on $K$ which implies the analyticity of $f$ by Morera as then we can switch integrals in $\int_{\Delta}f(s)ds$ for any triangle $\Delta \subset \Omega$.

Note that for $1 \le x \le 2C$ the integrals are clearly absolutely and uniformly bounded by a constant  so there is no problem, while for $0 \le x \le 1$ we use $\sin x \le x$ so $$\int_0^1 |x^{-s}\sin x|\,\mathrm{d}x \le \int_0^1 x^{1-b}dx<\infty$$ hence we just need to show uniform convergence on $[2C, \infty)$ and we will show uniform Cauchy so $|\int_A^B x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x| \to 0, A,B \to \infty, A,B \ge 2C, x \in K$

We write $$\int_A^B x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_A^B x^{-\sigma}(\cos (t \log x) - i \sin (t \log x))\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$$ so we need to analyze integrals of the type $$\int_A^B x^{-\sigma}\sin (x \pm t \log x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ and the same with cosine instead.

By the second mean value theorem for integrals there is $A \le B_s \le B$ st $$\int_A^B x^{-\sigma}\sin (x - t \log x)\,\mathrm{d}x=A^{-\sigma}\int_A^{B_s} \sin (x - t \log x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

But the derivative of $x - t \log x$ is $1-t/x$ so is between $1/2$ and $3/2$ and is monotonic since $|t/x| \le 1/2$ for $s \in K, x \ge A \ge 2C$ so with $h(x)=\sin (x - t \log x)$ we have  $\int_A^{B_s} \sin h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_A^{B_s} (h'(x)\sin h(x))/h'(x)dx$ so another application of the second mean value theorem gives that $$|\int_A^{B_s} (h'(x)\sin h(x))/h'(x)dx| \le (\max_{[A, B_s]}1/h')|\int_{A'}^{B'}h'(x)\sin h(x)dx| \le 4$$

(here $1/h'$ will be either increasing or decreasing depending on the sign of $t$ so the second mean value theorem applies at either end of the interval and the formula above covers both cases)

Hence  $$|\int_A^B x^{-\sigma}\sin (x - t \log x)\,\mathrm{d}x| \le 4A^{-\sigma} \le 4A^{-a}$$ and similarly for the other integrals involved, so $$|\int_A^B x^{-s}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x| \le 16A^{-a}$$ for all $x \in K$ and we are done

Comment: Very clear demonstration! Thank you!